# Use ESC/POS command to print Vietnames by thermal printer

Tags: c++, qt, thermal-printer

I'm currently using QT to send print commands to the Xp-D300H printer. Everything is working fine; I can print English text, images, and QR codes. However, I'm encountering issues with printing Vietnamese text.

```
My print text functions :  

int escpos_printer_text(escpos_printer *printer, QString content,const char *font,const char *type,const char *align)
{
    int result = 0;
    QTextCodec *isoCodec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
    QByteArray byteArray = isoCodec->fromUnicode(content);
    result = escpos_printer_raw(printer,byteArray.data(),byteArray.length());
    return result;
}

int escpos_printer_raw(escpos_printer *printer, const char * const message, const int len)
{
    assert(printer != NULL);
    //This function is using for send byte array to printer by Rs232
    printer->mRs232Printer->sendData(message,len);
    return 0;
}
```

The printer is functioning normally, but the characters with diacritics are currently displaying incorrectly.
It is result when i print "Hóa đơn bán hàng"
[image: Text image]

I have tried various encoding schemes. I have also sent the command to select the Vietnamese code page to the printer (0x1b 0x74 0x28). Additionally, I have turned off the '2 byte character' switch on the printer (because when it's on, the output is all in Chinese).

Comment: It seems that the printer you are using does not support Vietnamese or UTF-8 code pages. [XP-D230H/ XP-D300H 80mm Thermal Printer](https://www.xprintertech.com/receipt-printer-for-computer-xp-d300h-xp-d200h) If you want to print those characters, you will need to create them as image data and print the images.

Comment: @kunif i don't think that. becaus when I use it as a normal printer, connect to windows pc via usc port

Comment: The standard printer mechanism for Windows desktop PCs should process everything as image data.[Printing (Documents and Printing)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/printdocs-printing) For EPSON, the method is to print using the Advanced Printer Driver. [TM-T88VII>Software](https://support.epson.net/setupnavi/?PINF=swlist&OSC=WS&LG2=EN&MKN=TM-T88VII) If your XPrinter has such a device driver, you can use it.

Comment: By the way, for another XPrinter(XP-N160I), [Windows vietnamese codepage CP1258](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1258) is apparently [27 in decimal](https://github.com/kechankrisna/esc_pos_utils_plus/blob/nullable/lib/resources/capabilities.json#L145), so the third byte of the ESC/POS command will be 0x1B. It would be better to check the exact support for XP-D300H and parameter values.

Comment: @kunif yes, i checked. I printed all available third byte of the ESC/POS command and i sure that Vietnamese codepage is 28 in decimal.

Comment: @kunif CP1258 is terrible and no one uses it. Unicode would be much better. Because CP1258 isn't Unicode, passing it UTF-8 texts will produce wrong results. Or if the printer doesn't support UTF-8 then `QTextCodec::codecForName("CP1258");`

Comment: @phuclv , If you want to specify and print a string using the printer's font, you can only do so within the limited range supported by the printer. And there are very few thermal receipt printers that support UTF-8. For example, EPSON should only have models for India. It will be difficult to find with other vendors. If you want to print using Unicode, as I commented earlier, create everything as image data and print that image data. However, since you seem to be a printer vendor, if you have a printer that supports UTF-8, why not suggest it?

Comment: @kunif I don't know muc habout thermal printer. That's why I suggested a solution if the printer just support CP1258 above. The sent bytes must match the same encoding the printer expects